# pusher.js locking down client key permissions

Tags: pusher

Is there a way to make the client have only read-only permissions to channels since we are distributing the client key with the web app using the pusher.js sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application key itself does not determine the permissions of a client. It only identifies which application the client is connecting to.

By default all subscriptions are read-only. Pusher offers three channel types:

1. Public
2. [Private](https://pusher.com/docs/private_channels) - with a `private-` name prefix that also requires [subscription authentication](https://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users)
3. [Presence](https://pusher.com/docs/presence_channels) - with a `presence-` prefix that also require subscription authentication and additional functionality for adding functionality to show which users are subscribed to that channel

A above, in order to subscribe to either Private or Presence channels your server needs to authentication the subscription request.

If you actually want a client to be able to trigger events on channels you need to:

1. [Enable client events for an application](https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/207912408)
2. Subscribe to, and be authenticated for, a private or presence channel: `channel = pusher.subscribe('private-channel')`
3. Once subscribed (check using the `pusher:subscription_succeeded` callback) call `channel.trigger('client-event', eventData)` being sure to prefix the event name with `client-`